# CheckedTextView inside ListView: blinking issue upon selection

Tags: android

I have a ListView (in single choice mode) containing CheckedTextView items (with no checkmarks) and I have set appropriate selectors to determine the text color and the background color of the currently checked item.

What happens is the following:

1. I press an item of the ListView: the colors of the "selected" state (black over red) get correctly applied.
2. I release the item: it suddenly blinks back to the colors of the "default" state (white over black), for a fraction of a second.
3. After the short wrong blinking: the item correctly takes the colors of the "checked" state (black over red, which, by chance, are the same as the "selected" state).

Of course, **I need to get rid of such blinking effect** and I think that this should be fairly easy, but, unfortunately, I can't figure out what am I doing wrong!

Note that the wrong blinking effect only happens on pre-Honeycomb versions of Android (I've checked this both on emulators and physical devices).

I have already searched all over the Web and all over Stack Overflow to find an answer, so please do not address me to existing similar posts (unless they really resolve my issue, of course...).

In the following, you can find all the code needed to reproduce the issue I described above.

The activity (yes, it is a FragmentActivity of the compatibility library, but I really don't think it matters):

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TempListActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.temp_list);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tempListView);
    String[] array = new String[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.temp_list_item, array);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

}
```

The ListView:

```xml
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tempListView"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
</ListView>
```

The CheckedTextView used as a ListView item:

```xml
<CheckedTextView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item_title"  
android:height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_text_custom"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_custom"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The text color selector (list_item_text_custom.xml):

```xml
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:color="#000000">
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#000000">
</item>
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:color="#000000">
</item>
<item 
    android:color="#ffffff">
</item>
</selector>
```

The background color selector (list_item_custom.xml):

```xml
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/highlighted_item_background">
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/highlighted_item_background">
</item>
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/highlighted_item_background">
</item>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal_item_background">
</item>    
</selector>
```

The drawable for the highlighted background (highlighted_item_background.xml):

```xml
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ff0000" />    
</shape>
```

The drawable for the normal background (normal_item_background.xml):

```xml
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#000000" />    
</shape>
```

I would really like to leverage the standard Android selectors mechanism instead of being forced to find out some fancy workaround, so if I made any mistake in the code above, please let me know.

Otherwise, any help or alternative solution would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find a true solution for you, but if we simplify what you have, maybe we can find something acceptable as a compromise between what you'd like and what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal_item_background">
  </item>
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/highlighted_item_background">
  </item>
</selector>
```

Basically we keep the selection highlighted by default, and only set it to normal on when the item is *unchecked*.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Indeed your solution solves the blinking problem, but I think that removing the management of state_pressed is NOT acceptable.

As you probably already know, by doing this, the item does NOT get highlighted when the user puts her finger on the item until the user detaches the finger from the item, and this would be a very unusual and misleading effect for any user, in my opinion.

The problem seems related to the state_pressed management: for some reason, the item takes an intermediate state before going from state_pressed to state_checked, but which state?... Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never been able to get the desired behavior while using a color selector.  If you logically examine the xml - I think you have to conclude that something else is going on here in the updating of the list or listitem in the way it is drawn.  I can tell you that where it matters, we override the background color in getView() instead.

Comment: Thanks for your support and for sharing your experience about color selectors. Although it's quite frustrating that such a standard feature does not work as intended, I think that I will have to follow your advice. I don't mark your answer as accepted only because I hope that someone else had a better luck with color selectors and is willing to provide an alternative solution. Thanks again.